# D3.js qualitative calendar - adapt to string lookup function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to adapt a lookup function to accept a date and return a string for use with a calendar visual: a rect appended for each day of the year.

The original data format was:

```
day count
1/13/2020   1
1/15/2020   4
1/15/2020   2
2/17/2020   7
```

The calendar I am using as a template was originally designed with a heatmap in mind: if multiple observations fell on the same data, the lookup function would roll them together and add the values. This in turn was used to determine the fill.

The original lookup:

```
  var lookup = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.day; })
    .rollup(function(leaves) {
      return d3.sum(leaves, function(d){ return parseInt(d.count); });
    })
    .object(dateData);
```

Style was applied like this:

```
  var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range(["#003366","#b8cce4"])
      .domain([50,0]);

  rect.style('fill', function(d) {return lookup[d]>=0? colorScale((lookup[d])):"#d9d9d9"});
```

My data looks like this:

```
day type
1/13/2020   Bond
1/15/2020   Bond
1/19/2020   Index
2/17/2020   Balanced
```

Note that there are no repeating dates and instead of the integer:`count`, there will now be a string: `type`.

Snippet for reference:

```js
function drawCalendar(dateData){

  var weeksInMonth = function(month){
var m = d3.timeMonth.floor(month)
return d3.timeWeeks(d3.timeWeek.floor(m), d3.timeMonth.offset(m,1)).length;
  }

  var minDate = d3.min(dateData, function(d) { return new Date(d.day) })
  var maxDate = d3.max(dateData, function(d) { return new Date(d.day) })

  var cellMargin = 2,
  cellSize = 15;

  var day = d3.timeFormat("%w"),
  week = d3.timeFormat("%U"),
  format = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d"),
  titleFormat = d3.utcFormat("%a, %d-%b");
  monthName = d3.timeFormat("%B"),
  months= d3.timeMonth.range(d3.timeMonth.floor(minDate), maxDate);

  var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
.data(months)
.enter().append("svg")
.attr("class", "month")
.attr("height", ((cellSize * 7) + (cellMargin * 8) + 20) ) // the 20 is for the month labels
.attr("width", function(d) {
  var columns = weeksInMonth(d);
  return ((cellSize * columns) + (cellMargin * (columns + 1)));
})
.append("g")

  svg.append("text")
.attr("class", "month-name")
.attr("y", (cellSize * 7) + (cellMargin * 8) + 15 )
.attr("x", function(d) {
  var columns = weeksInMonth(d);
  return (((cellSize * columns) + (cellMargin * (columns + 1))) / 2);
})
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function(d) { return monthName(d); })

  var rect = svg.selectAll("rect.day")
.data(function(d, i) { return d3.timeDays(d, new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()+1, 1)); })
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("class", "day")
.attr("width", cellSize)
.attr("height", cellSize)
.attr("rx", 3).attr("ry", 3) // rounded corners
.attr("fill", '#eaeaea') // default light grey fill
.attr("y", function(d) { return (day(d) * cellSize) + (day(d) * cellMargin) + cellMargin; })
.attr("x", function(d) { return ((week(d) - week(new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),1))) * cellSize) + ((week(d) - week(new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),1))) * cellMargin) + cellMargin ; })
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed('hover', true);
})
.on("mouseout", function(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed('hover', false);
})
.datum(format);

  rect.append("title")
.text(function(d) { return titleFormat(new Date(d)); });


  var lookup = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.day; })
.rollup(function(leaves) {
  return d3.sum(leaves, function(d){ return parseInt(d.count); });
})
.object(dateData);

  var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain(d3.extent(dateData, function(d) { return parseInt(d.count); }))
.range([0.4,1]); // the interpolate used for color expects a number in the range [0,1] but i don't want the lightest part of the color scheme

  var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range(["#003366","#b8cce4"])
  .domain([50,0]);



  rect.style('fill', function(d) {return "#d9d9d9"});
  //rect.style('fill', function(d) {return lookup[d]>=0? colorScale((lookup[d])):"#d9d9d9"});

/*
  rect.filter(function(d) { return d in lookup; })
.style("fill", function(d) { return d3.interpolatePuBu(scale(lookup[d])); })
.select("title")
.text(function(d) { return titleFormat(new Date(d)) + ":  " + lookup[d]; });
*/
}

//d3.tsv("my-data.tsv", function(response){
  //drawCalendar(response);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

### Question

How can I adapt the lookup function/rect styling to accept the string data type in my data above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ordinal scale since the lookup is now returning categorical data.

To do so, you need to provide the unique `type`s within the data to the `domain` of the scale e.g.

```
// need unique types for ordinal scale
var uniqueTypes = Array.from(new Set(dateData.map(k => k.type)));

// set an ordinal scale with unique types
// and built in color scheme
var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)
  .domain(uniqueTypes);
```

If you prefer to use custom colours rather than a built in pallette, then you can still use the `range` of the scale to provide those e.g.

```
// need unique types for ordinal scale
var uniqueTypes = Array.from(new Set(dateData.map(k => k.type)));

// set an ordinal scale with unique types
// with custom colours 
var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(uniqueTypes)
  .range(["red", "green", "blue"]);
```

The lookup is more straightforward:

```
// new code for getting the color for the rect
rect.style("background-color", function(d) { // replace with fill for your real rects
  var color = colorScale(d.type);
  return color;
});
```

Since the `domain` is filled with unique types from your data, the check for a missing lookup is redundant (although you could add it back if you needed to).

Example:

```js
// your up-to-date data
var dateData = [
  {"day": "1/13/2020", "type": "Bond"},
  {"day": "1/15/2020", "type": "Bond"},
  {"day": "1/19/2020", "type": "Index"},
  {"day": "2/17/2020", "type": "Balanced"}
];

// need unique types for ordinal scale
var uniqueTypes = Array.from(new Set(dateData.map(k => k.type)));

// set an ordinal scale with unique types
// and built in color scheme
var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal() //(d3.schemeCategory10)
  .domain(uniqueTypes)
  .range(["red", "green", "blue"]);
  
// simulate adding rects
var rect = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll(".rectlike")
  .data(dateData)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .text(function(d) {return d.type;})
  .attr("class", "rectlike");

// new code for getting the color for the rect
rect.style("background-color", function(d) { // use fill for a rect
  var color = colorScale(d.type);
  console.log(color);
  return color;
});
```

```css
.rectlike {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```